# AWS ATHENA: METADATA and MANIFEST File

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Just want to ask about the behavior of manifest and metadata files. Are those two files created after the query finishes and generated output in s3 or will be created instantly when you start querying in athena?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation doesn't contain explicit information about this behavior, but using what's in there plus a quick test might shed some light on it.

According to the [Working with Query Results, Output Files, and Query History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html) documentation page we know a few things:

> Amazon Athena automatically stores query results and metadata information for each query that runs in a query result location that you can specify in Amazon S3. [...] Output files are saved automatically for every query that runs regardless of whether the query itself was saved or not.

Metadata files are always created and are closely related to query results; manifest files instead are only created for INSERT INTO kind of queries:

> Data manifest files are generated to track files that Athena creates in Amazon S3 data source locations when an INSERT INTO query runs. If a query fails, the manifest also tracks files that the query intended to write.

I have tried to run a query, as you can see it was executed at 11:29:53 UTC and it lasted 20.52s.
[image: Athena query history]

Inspecting the metadata object at the corresponding location, we can see that the object was last modified at 11:30:14 UTC (~20sec after query was submitted).
[image: Metadata object head]
[image: Metadata object info]

Based on the above - which admittedly is not a statistically significative sample - we can see that the metadata file is created sometime **after the query is submitted and before it has finished running**.

Given the fact that AWS doesn't specify this anywhere, my suggestion would be to not rely on the fact that the file is present or not to track query execution/completion. If this is your use case, you should instead check the status of the query via API using the corresponding `QueryId`.